# Creating a copy of selected worksheets in a workbook and pasting only the values into another and retains formatting of source

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to create a "Report Printer" that takes selected worksheets and pastes only the values into another workbook while retaining the formatting.

The document I'm using is a very large workbook (lets call it the source) that contains a lot of formula, links and macro within it, there are several (6 to be exact) "report" pages that takes information from the working sheets and displays them in a nice way. I'm trying to find a way to take these report pages into another workbook and turn them into value only and retain all the lovely formatting.

I've tried this macro

```
`Sub copyPrintValues()

Dim ReportPrintOutput As Workbook
Dim Current As String
Dim FileName As String

Set ReportPrintOutput = ThisWorkbook
Current = ThisWorkbook.FullName

Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Dim SH As Worksheet
For Each SH In ReportPrintOutput.Worksheets

    SH.UsedRange.Copy
    SH.UsedRange.PasteSpecial xlPasteColumnWidths
    SH.UsedRange.PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
    SH.UsedRange.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, _
        Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=True, Transpose:=False

Next

Worksheets("WorkSheet1").Delete

FileName = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & Pre & ThisWorkbook.Name & "_ReportPrint.xlsx"
ReportPrintOutput.SaveAs FileName, XlFileFormat.xlOpenXMLWorkbook
Workbooks.Open Current
PrintOutput.Close
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub`
```

The theory I was thinking was copy to everything across to the output then just delete the worksheets in the output that I don't need (via vba).

Any suggestions would be a huge help, I've been pulling my hair out trying to get it to work!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Save a temporary copy of the source file, then for each sheet run `UsedRange.Value = UsedRange.Value` to remove the formulas (or just do that on your "report" sheets). Now you can delete the sheets you don't want to keep.

```
Sub NoFormulas()

    Dim wbTemp As Workbook, tempPath As String, sht As Worksheet, wbReport As Workbook
    Dim ReportPrintOutput As Workbook
    Dim Current As String
    Dim FileName As String

    tempPath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & "temp_" & ThisWorkbook.Name

    ThisWorkbook.SaveCopyAs tempPath
    Set wbTemp = Workbooks.Open(tempPath)
    For Each sht In wbTemp.Worksheets
        sht.UsedRange.Value = sht.UsedRange.Value
    Next sht

    wbTemp.Sheets(Array("Sheet1", "Sheet3")).Copy '<< copy the needed sheets to a new workbook
    Set wbReport = ActiveWorkbook
    wbReport.SaveAs ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Report.xlsx"

    wbTemp.Close False 'close and delete the temporary copy
    Kill tempPath

End Sub
```